# Finding the parity of a permutation "exclusively"?

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

I'm trying to find the parity of permutations such as $(2468)$.

What makes it possible to find the "exclusive" parity of such permutation? I.e. that if one tries to express $(2468)$ as a product of disjoint permutations and then counts the number of them, then one could infer the parity (and that the parity cannot be anything else than of what was found in expressing it as the product of disjoint permutations)?

E.g. how can I conclude $(2468)$ as being odd or even?

Is it enough to find one expression in product of disjoint permutations and if its parity is even then the parity of the original permutation cannot be odd?

---

[This Wikipedia example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation#Example) for example seems contradictory as it expresses an expression first as the composition of 2 (even) and then 3 permutations (odd). But concludes that the parity is odd.

Comment: It is better to think of permutations taking parity +1 even or -1 odd. A cycle of length $n$ has parity $(-1)^{n+1}$. If you compose permutations you multiply their parities, so if $\sigma$ is even and $\tau$ is odd then $\sigma\tau$ is odd.

Answer (score 2):

To expand upon Bernard's answer, the parity of a non-identity permutation $\pi \in S_{n}$ is the parity of the number of transpositions used when $\pi$ is expressed as a product of transpositions ( a transposition is a $2$-cycle). That this is well-defined takes some work- there are many ways to do it, covered in many algebra texts.

Depending on which way you compose your permutations, an $m$-cycle is expressible as a product of $m-1$ transpositions, eg
$(12...m) = (12)(13)(14)\ldots (1m)$.

Every permutation is expressible as a product of disjoint cycles of various lengths, so once you know that the parity of a permutation is well-defined, it becomes routine to calculate the parity of any permutation.

Comment: Just to stress a point in this very good answer, you need to write the permutation as a product of $2$-cycles (that, as the example shows, are not generally disjoint) before thinking about parity. (There are shortcuts, but *by (one) definition*, this is the way).

Comment: @Geoff Robinson: Don't you think the decomposition $(12)(23)\dotsm(m-1\,m)$ is more obvious for beginners?

Comment: @Bernard: It depends how good you are at compositing permutations!

Answer (score 0):

The parity of a cycle of length $n$ is $n-1$.